# How to use local param in $controller service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could someone explain me how to use `local` parameter for this service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller
I'm doing like so:

```
let locals = { '$scope': Scope, 'parameters': parameters };
ctrlInstance = $controller(controller, locals);
```

Im my context parameters just an `int` value but I can't find it in my instance and inside the controller code `this.parameters` always undefined.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `locals` parameter passed to the `$controller` service contains the variables available for injection in your controller. The `key` in `locals` is the name by which you can request the variable (the `value`) to be injected.

The `parameters` in your case may be injected into controller this way:

```
function MyController($scope, parameters) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my life!